# Prevent input box from stealing focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a chrome extension that displays an input when I click onto a specific icon on that page.

I can enter something into that input, but once I clicked elsewhere I cannot give the focus back to that input no matter how often I click into that input again.

The reason why that happens is that the website itself (which I cannot modify) always focusses on a textarea on that page and so the text is entered there.

I already tried stuff like the following:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.giphySearch input', function () {
            var input=this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                input.focus();
            })
        });
```

But with no real effort (it only seems to slow everything down; But the input still loses focus)

Is there any way to disable all "focus stealing"-scripts and turn them on again after my work is done?

(I know the class of the textbox that always gets the focus from the page. I cannot however change anything on that page, because I am inside a chrome extension)

Just for completion:
The input I am talking about:

```
<div class="giphySearch"><input  autofocus type="text" value="huih"/></div>
```

Comment: You could try $('.giphySearch').off() or $('.giphySearch input').off(). It should get rid of all eventlisteners that were added with .on(). Docs: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: I answered a similar question a few days ago, may I ask you to look here and tell me if it is relevant for your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690669/contenteditable-events-jquery/51690805#51690805

Comment: you may try to disable pointer events...... and after reenabling them:  **pointer-events: none;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by moving my content to another part of the DOM (to be exactly: Directly under the `<body/>`.

So that behavior seemed to be because one of the parents of my div.

I think in my specific case this is the "cleanest" way even though the answer from @ibowankenobi may be a more generic one more suitable for others: [Contenteditable Events - Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690669/contenteditable-events-jquery/51690805#51690805)

Comment: You should not put content outside of the body element.

Comment: When I wrote "under" I meant "child of", not "below" :)