# Prevent onBlur event to execute when clicking the clear button using redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, onblur

i have a redux form which is have a submit button and a clear button. The clear button is dispatching the reset function which is given as a property in redux form.My code is here:

```
<UsernameField
      name={NEW_USERNAME}
      onBlurFn={e => checkUsername(e.target.value)}
    />


<button className="gray" type="button" onClick={clearUsernameForm}>
      <FormattedMessage id="customer.clear.button" />
    </button>

    export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  clearUsernameForm: () => dispatch(reset(CHANGE_USERNAME_FORM)),
  /**
   * It requests to check if username already exists
   */
  checkUsername: (value) => {
    dispatch(checkSettingsUsernameAction(value, CHANGE_USERNAME_FORM, NEW_USERNAME));
  },
});
```

My problem is that when i click the clear button my the onBlur event is firing. How to prevent this?

Comment: See my answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690669/contenteditable-events-jquery/51690805#51690805

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. but there must be a simpler way to do this using redux form

Comment: You might consider playing around with pointer-events css momentarily, but for that you'll need to add a class with js as well. If you find cleaner solution, do let me know.